# Get value to text box by comparing two values from Two combo boxes

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new to javascript can you please help me.
 
I have two combo boxes of Pass type and Duration in my form. I want to assign amount in text box when user select values from pass type and duration.
For example If I select 'visitor' from pass type and 'annual' from duration i want to assign 2000 to amount textbox. 
I have tried this but in amount it get **undefined** 
Here is My code :

```
<form method="post" action="#" class="contact_insert"><br><br> 
    <table align="center" >
        <td> <h3>Pass Type:</h3></td>
        <td> <span>
            <select  name="pass_type" onchange="getpass(this);">
            <option value="">Select from here..</option>
            <option value="Visitor">Visitor</option>
            <option value="Bike">Bike</option>
            <option value="Van">Van</option>
            <option value="Car">Car</option>
            <option value="Three Wheel">Three Wheel</option>
            <option value="Heavy Vehicle">Heavy Vehicle</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
            </select>
        </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <h3>Duration Type:</h3></td>
        <td> <span>
            <select  id="duration_type" name="duration_type" onchange="javascript:dynamicdropdown(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); getduw(this);">
            <option value="">Select from here..</option>
            <option value="Annual" onchange="setSelect('Annual')">Annual</option>
            <option value="Quarter" onchange="setSelect('Quarter')">Quarter</option>
            <option value="Monthly" onclick="setSelect('Monthly')">Monthly</option>
            </select>
            </span></td>
        </span></td>
        </tr>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function dynamicdropdown(listindex)
            {
                switch (listindex)
                {
                    case "Annual" :
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[1]=new Option("2019","2019");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[2]=new Option("2020","2020");
                    break;

                    case "Quarter" :
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[1]=new Option("January1-March31","January1-March31");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[2]=new Option("April1-June30","April1-June30");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[3]=new Option("July1-September30","July1-September30");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[4]=new Option("October1-December31","October1-December31");
                    break;

                    case "Monthly" :
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[0]=new Option("Select status","");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[1]=new Option("January","January");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[2]=new Option("February","February");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[3]=new Option("March","March");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[4]=new Option("April","April");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[5]=new Option("May","May");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[6]=new Option("June","June");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[7]=new Option("July","July");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[8]=new Option("August","August");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[9]=new Option("September","September");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[10]=new Option("October","October");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[11]=new Option("November","November");
                        document.getElementById("duration").options[12]=new Option("December","December");
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <tr>
        <td> <h3>Duration:</h3></td>
        <td> <span>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            document.write('<select name="duration" id="duration"><option value="">Select from here</option></select>')
            </script>
            <noscript>
            <select  id="duration" name="duration">
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
            </select>
            </noscript>
        </span></td>
        </tr>                  
        <tr>
        <td> <h3>Amount:</h3></td>
        <td width="75%"><span><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" readonly></span></td>
        </tr><script>
            var str;
            var xy;

            function getpass(e)
            {
            var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;                  
            //alert(str);
            }

            function getduw(x)
            {
            var xy = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;                    
            // alert(xy);                    
            }

            if(str =='Visitor')
            {
                if(xy=='Annual')
                {
                    document.getElementById('amount').value = 200;
                }
                elseif (xy=='Quarter') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('amount').value=315;           
                }
                elseif (xy=='Monthly') 
                {
                    document.getElementById('amount').value=105;           
                }
            }
            elseif(str=='Bike' || str=='Van' || str=='Car' || str=='Three Wheel')
            {
                if(xy=='Annual')
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=600;
                }
                elseif (xy=='Quarter') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=500;           
                }
                elseif (xy=='Monthly') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=155;           
                }
            }
            elseif(str=='Heavy Vehicle' )
            {
                if(xy=='Annual')
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=2000;
                }
                elseif (xy=='Quarter') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=1500;           
                }
                elseif (xy=='Monthly') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=520;           
                }
            }
            elseif(str=='Other' )
            {
                if(xy=='Annual')
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=1300;
                }
                elseif (xy=='Quarter') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=1500;           
                }
                elseif (xy=='Monthly') 
                {
                document.getElementById('amount').value=520;           
                }
            }
        </script>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="save" type="submit" class="btn" id="save" value="Submit" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML here, and how are you calculating the amount?

Comment: share your html, and the example for more clear your problem

Comment: @kunal  I update my code

Comment: @illuminarch I update my html and script code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example what you want, you can improve this answer to fit your requirement.
Hope it helps.

You need using `onchange` function to get each value from your select option, and calculate it.

```js
$('.count').on('change', function(){

    let pass_type = $('#pass_type').val();
    let duration = $('#duration').val();

    $('#total').val(pass_type * duration);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="pass_type">Pass Type</label>
<select name="pass_type" id="pass_type" class="count">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="200">Visitor</option>
 <option value="100">Bike</option>
</select>
<br>
<label for="duration">Duration</label>
<select name="duration" id="duration" class="count">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="600">Annual</option>
 <option value="500">Quarter</option>
 <option value="155">Monthly</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" readonly>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed to this in my code,    $('.count').change(function(){});